# How can I update two models in one serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a database schema that has each object of a certain type being stored across two separate tables (one row in each table, different data in each, with a foreign key from one to the other.)

Unfortunately, Django Rest Framework tends to assume that there is a one to one correspondence between serializers and models, which is not true of my case.  How should I be approaching this?  It seems like the serializer should return the representation of the object which will be the actual HTTP response of the ajax requests, so using two serializers doesn't seem right.  I've looked at extending BaseSerializer (which is how I currently plan to implement this if I don't find better solutions), but certain methods take in an `instance`, which should contain all the data needed to serialize the object, whereas I have two instances relevant.

Any advice would be super appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Writable nested representations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) section might help you.

You have 2 models `ModelA` and `ModelB`. Create your first model's serializer

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('fields',..) #
```

Then in other model's serializer add the first serializer and override the required methods (like `create`, `update`). Something like this:

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # add the serializer for the foreignkey model 
    model_a = ModelASerializer()   

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('fields',..) # 

   def create(self, validated_data):
       modela_data = validated_data.pop('model_a')
       model_b = ModelB.objects.create(**validated_data)
       ModelA.objects.create(model_b=model_b, **modela_data)
       return model_b

   # override update too ..
```

Comment: I am new to rest framework and I am getting problems in updation, my model B data is showing in fields when I go to update page but it is not showing model A data in those fields what should I do, I have check so many answers but I am unable to get the data of both models in fields at the time of updating in browser...

Comment: now How to apply this in views.py @Tiny Instance

Comment: Thanks [This link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) helped me