# How to implement JWT authentication in web app after a registered user logs in?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and I want to implement JWT authentication in order to view an API data for the **currently** logged-in user, only. Can someone please give me a hint on how to structure the implementation of JWT in Django (version 2.1)?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt)?

Comment: Yes, I am already using this package but whenever I gain the access token after logging in, I am obtaining **all** of the data in my model. However, I just want to return data specific to the user who is currently logged in. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can create a seaparate `APIView` with `IsAuthenticated` permission and return the `request.user` from that endpoint.

Comment: Can you confirm which package are you using for the JWT?

Comment: @ShakibHossain I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @JaskaranSingh using this link :https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mentioned you are using both `django-rest-framework` and `django-rest-framework-simplejwt`. I would suggest creating a separate `APIView` for getting the details of the currently logged in user. You should create a serializer for the `User` model as well.

If you added the below declaration in your settings correctly, then the currently authenticated user should be available within `request.user`.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Something like this should suffice in your case:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserDetailsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        profile = request.user.profile
        data = {
            'username': request.user.username,
            'email': request.user.email,
            'salary': profile.salary,
            'company': profile.company,
            'address': profile.address,
            'gender': profile.gender,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: I have created another model named Profile which contains: id (Foreign key to the User Model), salary, company, address, and gender. I want the API to show me the logged in user's username, email, and the following fields mentioned above. But this would require two models within a single queryset. Is there a way to join both models and get results from both tables?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Kindly check and accept answer if it solves your problem. Otherwise, let me know.

Comment: You don't need to define another queryset to get the profile. One question though, shouldn't a `Profile` be an `OneToOneField` with `User` rather than being a ForeignKey?

Comment: It worked! Can you please explain the steps taken? What does 'IsAuthenticated' mean? And why did you use **request.user.profile** in your code?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is a OneToOneField. I was mistaken. Thank you

Comment: `IsAuthenticated` ensures that only logged in users will be able to access that view ([documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)). And I assumed that `profile` was the field related to the `User` that's why I used `request.user.profile`.

Comment: Just one more thing, I want to create a Registration API as well. As you know, I am currently using two models (User and Profile). My serializers.py file needs to contain both the User Model and Profile Model in order to fill in the necessary fields (username, email, password, gender, salary, address and company). Do you have any ways to implement two models in a Serializer? I have already created a serializers.py module but the POST request doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @jelly_bean maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782201/5031391)?

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I'll post a new question regarding it, it will be great if you could take a look at it.