# How to combine two different Models in serializers module (Django)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to create a Registration API, wherein, I aim to combine the User Model and Profile Model in order to create a new user by adding the username, email, password (User Model fields) and gender, salary, company, and address (Profile Model fields). I attempted to use the source from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781625/how-can-i-update-two-models-in-one-serializer-in-django-rest-framework/39782201#39782201). However, I am not able to POST any data in. This is my code so far:

views.py:

```
class RegisterAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             return Response("Thank you for registering", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['gender', 'company', 'salary', 'address']

class RegisterBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   #User Model serializer
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(password)
        user.save() 
        Profile.objects.create(user = user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

Can anyone hint me on where I am going off-track?.

I am not able to add data via DRF:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sag1b.png)

Usually, I should be getting a Body which states:

```
{"username" : "this field is required",
"email" : "this field is required",
"password" : "this field is required", (will be hashed using set_password())
"gender" : "this field is required",} etc etc...
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try to POST?

Comment: In your **RegisterAPIView** class change **ProfileSerializer** with **RegisterBSerializer** class.

Comment: @ShakibHossain Please view the image above.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Yes, I tried that, but still doesn't work. Please view the image above for a clearer illustration of what I meant. Thank you

Comment: @jelly_bean that is because of permissions. Check DRF permissions [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) and set your default permissions.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh But why would you need permissions for a Registration API view? I mean, anyone can access it and use it, right?

Comment: @jelly_bean in your **views.py** `from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny` and in your **RegisterAPIView** class add `permission_classes = [AllowAny]`

Comment: As pointed by @JagjeetSingh your image shows a login/permission issue. Either fix that and update the image or change the issue title & body as it is not related to the two different models - which is likely another issue you got.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Wow, this worked! But why should I set the permission_classes to 'AllowAny'? Also, I am only seeing the username, email and password fields to be filled. Fields such as Gender, Salary, Address and Company cant be seen. Do I need to specify these fields in under the User Model in my serializer?

Comment: @jelly_bean Most of our API's requires authentication. So, that we set default permission as **IsAuthenticated** in the settings.py. And in some API's where we don't requires any authentication in such cases we define `permission_classes = [AllowAny]` in their view class.

Comment: What about the remaining fields in the serializer? Currently, only the username, email, and password can be filled. The other fields such as gender, company etc are not inputted. Should I include them in the fields under the RegisterBSerializer?

Comment: @jelly_bean You have to add the `profile` field to the `RegisterBSerializer`'s Meta `fields` property. (Line 15 according to your code example)

Comment: @ShakibHossain I've done that, but in POSTMAN, how can I specify those fields? If I insert only the 'profile' field under Meta class, how can I specify them in POSTMAN since I am only seeing the 'profile' field?

Comment: `"profile": { "gender": "M", }` try like this add the other fields too to the `profile` object.

Comment: Thanks, man. I'll get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing custom `to_representation` method like this

```
class RegisterBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   #User Model serializer
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        profile = data.pop('profile', {})
        data.update(profile)
        return data
```